# Why mongodb giving such a serial problems one to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am very stuck at this point and i dont know how can i solve such a sql problem. Can you help me ( junior buddy ) foralso identifying and get on solve this problem.
I think database which is mongodb giving me some error for any reason well its different because idont know why this happens to me . nothing changed too far.andi dont know why stackoverflow says itstoomuch code , its not even code , just an error message.
Thank you very much , it is very kind of you brother.

````
> nodemon app.js

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:8492) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-neqnf.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:406:14)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:294:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:561:14
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:1008:9
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:31:7
    at callback (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:264:5)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:294:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
(node:8492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-02-neqnf.mongodb.net:27017]
on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:406:14)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:294:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:561:14
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:1008:9
    at C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:31:7
    at callback (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:264:5)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBG\Desktop\SadıkTuran\19noSQL-Mongo\noSql\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:294:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:478:8)
(node:8492) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8492) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: It's fairly obvious that your application is not connecting to MongoDB (i.e. `connection timed out`). This could be either a firewall issue or you're simply using the wrong endpoint.

Comment: It seems like you are not able to connect to your `MongoDB`  this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076