# Heroku would not connect to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I know this question had been asked before, but I'm seriously not finding an answer to this issue anywhere.

I deployed a Node.js app to Heroku successfully, but I cannot connect to my MongoDB Atlas cluster. 
This is the error I get:

```js
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723516+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection failed... MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to 54.72.180.237:27017 closed
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723526+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new MongooseServerSelectionError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/serverSelection.js:22:11)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723527+00:00 app[web.1]:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:808:32)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723529+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:333:15)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723530+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:22:4)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723531+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723531+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723532+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723532+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723532+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723533+00:00 app[web.1]:   message: 'connection <monitor> to 54.72.180.237:27017 closed',
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723534+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723534+00:00 app[web.1]:   reason: TopologyDescription {
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723535+00:00 app[web.1]:     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723535+00:00 app[web.1]:     setName: null,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723535+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxSetVersion: null,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723536+00:00 app[web.1]:     maxElectionId: null,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723536+00:00 app[web.1]:     servers: Map {
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723537+00:00 app[web.1]:       'milenskiblog-shard-00-00-lkwi4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723537+00:00 app[web.1]:       'milenskiblog-shard-00-01-lkwi4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723538+00:00 app[web.1]:       'milenskiblog-shard-00-02-lkwi4.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723539+00:00 app[web.1]:     },
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723539+00:00 app[web.1]:     stale: false,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723539+00:00 app[web.1]:     compatible: true,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723540+00:00 app[web.1]:     compatibilityError: null,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723540+00:00 app[web.1]:     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723541+00:00 app[web.1]:     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723541+00:00 app[web.1]:     localThresholdMS: 15,
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723541+00:00 app[web.1]:     commonWireVersion: null
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723542+00:00 app[web.1]:   },
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723542+00:00 app[web.1]:   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
2020-04-07T10:39:20.723542+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

This is how I connect to MongoDB:

```js
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.blog_db, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB..."))
  .catch((err) => console.error(`Connection failed...`, err));
```

And this is my environment variable (which I set exactly the same in Heroku).[image]

The weird thing is, if I run nodemon index.js the app runs perfectly and it connects to the MongoDB Atlas cluster immediately, but the deployed heroku app doesnt seem to connect to the DB. 
I am literally out of ideas and I'm plucking my hair here, so please if anyone had tackled this issue before, I need your help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076 this will help you

Comment: God bless you brother, I can't believe I didn't find that myself!