# Unable to connect to Mongodb Atlas using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect to a cluster created in Mongodb Atlas using mongoose in node js and I am facing below issues when doing so.

1. When I use the connection string that is given in the Mongo db atlas`mongodb+srv://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-q5biw.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`I get below error

   { Error: queryTxt EBADNAME lmdev-q5biw.mongodb.net
       at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:196:19)
     errno: 'EBADNAME',
     code: 'EBADNAME',
     syscall: 'queryTxt',
     hostname: 'lmdev-q5biw.mongodb.net'}

I cannot use this connection string in Mongodb Compass as well as I am getting the same error there.

2. If I try to connect using `mongodb://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net/test` i get below error

   MongooseServerSelectionError: connection  to 54.66.221.230:27017 closed

However I am able to connect to each node using Mongodb Compass which eliminates the possibility of my ipaddress not being whitelisted.

Here is the sample code that I am using

```
const mongoosePromise = mongoose.connect("mongodb://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    replicaSet: "LMDEV"
}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successful");
    }
});
```

Any thoughts on what is happening here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076 check this

Comment: @kedarsedai I already did. But I am able to connect using Mongodb Compass from the same machine indicating that it is not a problem with IP Address.

Comment: You are trying to connect to `MongoDB Atlas` to your` Node` Application?

Comment: Did you remove `<> angle brackets` and put your password there?

Comment: @kedarsedai Yes I did. And I am trying to connect to my cluster that I created on Mongodb Atlas from my Node application.

Comment: `const mongoose = require('mongoose')`  and here is the simple code to connect so, try this 
`mongoose
     .connect( 'mongodb://lm_dev_app:password@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net/test'.   { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
     .then(() => console.log( 'Database Connected' ))
     .catch(err => console.log( err ));`

Comment: @kedarsedai I think i figured it out. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things that I need to highlight here.

1. The default connection string that is shown in MongoDB Atlas seems to be wrong. It shows you:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster_url>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

But I used `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<node_url>:27017/` to make it work.
You can also use `mongodb://<username>:<password>@<node_url>:27017/admin`.

2. Pass `ssl:true` in the options that we are passing.
3. Finally one of the 3 options can be used to connect to the database:

a.

```
const mongoosePromise = mongoose.connect("mongodb://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net:27017/", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        authSource:"admin",
        ssl: true,
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successful");
        }
    });
```

b.

```
const mongoosePromise = mongoose.connect("mongodb://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net:27017/", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        authSource:"admin",
        ssl: true,
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successful");
        }
    });
```

c.

```
const mongoosePromise = mongoose.connect("mongodb://lm_dev_app:<password>@lmdev-shard-00-01-q5biw.mongodb.net:27017/admin", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        ssl: true,
    }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Successful");
        }
    });
```

---

After having  a chat with the Atlas support team I was told that issue in point 1 is due to DNS resolution issue with my service provider. So I have changed my DNS settings to point to a public DNS server.

Comment: Oh god ! How can you make  your connection string wrong ?

Comment: @kedarsedai I am assuming that it is wrong since Mongodb Compass constructed a different connection string compared to the connection string provided on Mongodb Atlas.

Comment: Okay fine well researched.

Comment: Thanks @SachinKumar found your answer after wasting 12 hours.

Comment: What is the difference between cluster_url and node_url?

Answer (score 1):

After trying different connection strings for several hours, I finally just copy/pasted the connection string from MongoDB Compass and it works! (first connect, then edit the connection string as it will change)

It looks like this:

`mongodb+srv://username:password@fra-atlas-shard.abcde.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-abcde-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true`