# Why does local Robo3t connect to a remote Mongo DB instance, but NodeJs fails with IP whitelist error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issues connecting to MongoDb running remotely, and the connection error response I am getting from the server is somewhat weird.

My network access whitelist is set to allow all (0.0.0.0/0). Hence, my local robo3t installation was able to connect. However, I could not connect from my NodeJs code. Error is: "MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist"

IP whitelist seems to be an unlikely error, given that my local robo3t client is able to connect remotely to the same remote Mongo Atlas instance, as IP whitelist is allow-all.

How do I debug this kind of thing, please?

**UPDATE:** this is how I connect to MongoDb. Works well on local, too.

```
try {
    const connectionString =
        process.env.APP_ENV == "test"
            ? await getInMemoryMongoDbAdapter()
            : `mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_HOSTNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PORT}/${process.env.CBT_DATABASE_NAME}`;

    logger.info(`Connecting to MongoDB service: ${connectionString}`);
    

    await mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
} catch (error) {
    reject(error);
}
```

The logger line correctly shows: `Connecting to MongoDB service: mongodb://<user>:<password>@cluster0-xxx.yyy.zzz.net:<port>/<database>`

**UPDATE 2**:
My localhost also does not connect via this node app; whereas my robo3t (local MongoDb client) connects. I guess that means Heroku-specific issues can now be comfortably ruled out

Comment: Hello, please show us what you tried so far. The code regarding mongo connection.

Comment: You can try two things: 1. remove the options from the connect method , 2: if you have an antivirus like ESET or firewall, make sure that it doesn't block the app for requesting outside access.

Comment: `telnet` and `ping` works, so I do not think it is firewall/AV issue; plus I'm on Linux. Removing the options throws all kinds of deprecation warnings, expectedly (the mongoose docs advised to use those option flags specifically). Weirdly, my localhost also cannot connect to this Mongo Atlas db. I am updating the question now to reflect this...

Comment: Can you update your whitelist with `0.0.0.0/0,::/0`, both `ipv4` and `ipv6`

Comment: I get error when attempting to add `::/0`. The error details is: `This is neither a valid IP address nor CIDR notation: ::/0`

Comment: Changing it to `::ffff:0000:0000` gives a clearer error message: `IPv6 addresses are not supported for the network permission list`

Comment: Have you tried another `mongo` package ? Or the cli connection `mongo "mongodb://<host>:<port>"` ? I'm running out of ideas here ...

Comment: Yes man. I appreciate your efforts. I just tried mongo shell a few minutes ago. It connects perfectly well. This rules out both Heroku and Mongo Atlas issues, and leaving my node js code as the only culprit. I'm fresh out of ideas man!

Comment: I am using [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) for my nodejs. It connects to my local instance of `mongod` running on `localhost`. It does not connect to the MongoDb Atlas remote db. [Robo3t](https://robomongo.org/), a mongodb client running on my local, connects to to the same remote Mongo Atlas that my node app (mongoose) cannot connect to

Comment: Just tried your code and it worked, mind you set the connection in a variable and console.log it `let conn = await mongoose.connect(...);  console.log(conn);`, it worked for me. Or even better `resolve(await mongoose.connect(...))` or return that line

Comment: Hey @darklightcode it finally worked! Thanks for your effort. Very kind of you! I got the clue from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172094/1823554).
Writing an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decade later, I found that for the connection parameters, I needed to supply the `authSource` and `ssl` options, as below:

```
{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    authSource: "admin",
    ssl: true,
}
```

Neither one works without the other. Big shout-out to [@darklightcode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2076949/darklightcode) for all the insights he gave, leading me to dig deeper. Thanks man!