# MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms, using heroku to deploy

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need your help to connect my mongodb database to the cluster atlas, I configured my IP, username and password. I'm using heroku to deploy. Thanks for help! But I can't , see bellow:

> express: "^4.17.1",
>      express-session: "^1.17.0",
>      mongoose: "^5.8.3",

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = { mongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://username:password@blog-prod-upfzz.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority' }    
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(db.mongoURI, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully');
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
      });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076

Answer (score 1):

You need to whitelist the server IP. See [here](https://help.heroku.com/JS13Y78I/i-need-to-whitelist-heroku-dynos-what-are-ip-address-ranges-in-use-at-heroku) for how to determine which IPs to whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

I've added my IP to the whitelist and IP anywhere but isn't working. I read the link, but I don't understand how it can me help, sorry..