# trouble connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am following a tutorial and trying to connect to mongodb, i have two files
the first is server.js with the following codes

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//DB config

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

//connect to mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(()=>console.log('Connected to mongodb...'))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`server connected on port ${port}`));
```

The second is the config file

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI:'mongodb+srv://denis:password@shoppingapp-wmnbw.mongodb.net/shopping?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
}
```

what I am trying to achieve is to show on the console `connected to mongodb...`
instead I am given this error message

```
server connected on port 5000
(node:35030) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [shoppingapp-shard-00-01-wmnbw.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to shoppingapp-shard-00-01-wmnbw.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:372:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at net.js:672:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:557:7)]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at /home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
    at /home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1008:9
    at callback (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:97:5)
    at /home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:124:7
    at _callback (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:349:5)
    at Connection.errorHandler (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:365:5)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/denis/Desktop/projects/MERN_SHOPPING_LIST/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:370:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:26)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at net.js:672:12
    at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:557:7)
```

I have tried to change the driver version but still get the errors, where am I going wrong?

Comment: if those are your real credentials, you should probably hide your mongo uri string from public

Comment: The password is not correct

Comment: `.connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true  }) `  this will remove your `Deprecation Warning` and can you have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was not connecting with the right IP address.