# I still get the MongooseServerSelectionError after allowing all access from anywhere when i connect with heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I have succeeded in moving my codes to heroku, set up my environment variables. I chose the `Allow access from anywhere` when whitelisting my IP but I still get this error

```
 An error occurred: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
```

I have used fixie which is an addon in heroku to generate static IP address and I added this static address to my list of whitelisted IPs and I still get the same issue.

I do not know what I am doing wrong

Here is my connection string

```
mongodb+srv://test_user:<password>@test-cluster.86mbw.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

my mongoose version is `5.9.16`

Comment: Can you connect from your laptop/home computer?

Comment: And provide complete error output.

Comment: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

Comment: I cannot connect to Mongo's remote datadbase. I still get the same mongooseServerSelectionError as stated above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076 did you try this ?

Comment: You have not whitelisted the IP or your cluster is not running.

Comment: I have done that. I even allowed access from anywhere.