# Trouble connecting to MongoDB Atlas (NodeJS, GoDaddy)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I've successfully deployed my NodeJS app to GoDaddy. The problem however, is I cannot connect to MongoDB Atlas. The app successfully connects to Atlas while hosted on Heroku but the client really wants it on GoDaddy.

Can anyone help?

Here's the connection code (I left the user/pass/db fields arbitrary for obvious reasons):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0.fl4tg.mongodb.net/db? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: 
true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error'));
```

Here's what displays in the PuTTY terminal when starting the app:

```
Server started!
MongoDB connection error { MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/home/e6wbesvq0ia5/public_html/nodejs.shiftmediamanagement.com/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:878:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason:
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 34.206.112.25:27017
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
     name: 'MongoNetworkError',
     errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
     [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:2808162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/home/e6wbesvq0ia5/public_html/nodejs.shiftmediamanagement.com/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:878:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
(node:2808162) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2808162) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076  you can have a look

Comment: As kedar sedai says, you have to whitelist your IP in the mongodb admin ui

Comment: I tried whitelisting the specific IP to no avail. And I've tried whitelisting all IPs to no avail. I think maybe it has to do with limitations of shared hosting. Just purchased a VPS, I'll keep you all updated. Thank you for the responses!

Comment: UPDATE: Using a VPS solved my problem