# How to resolve UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in mongodb altlas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to connect mongoose using MongoDB atlas
but I am getting one warning like this below

> Database Connected bro (node:763272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> MongooseServerSelectionError: connection  to
> 34.234.233.64:27017 closed
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:845:32)
> at _mongoose._promiseOrCallback.cb (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10)
> at Promise (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5)
> at new Promise ()
> at promiseOrCallback (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
> at Mongoose.connect (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
> at Object. (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/backend/server.js:12:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
> at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
> at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3) (node:763272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:763272) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My server.js file is code

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser:true,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology:true} 
    );
    mongoose
    .connect( uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => console.log( 'Database Connected bro' ))
    .catch(err => console.log( err ))
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'd appreciate if i can get some guidance with this issue.

Comment: Looks like configuring your ip address in Atlas would help you here. Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584076/8308259.

Comment: not working throwing this error server is running on port 5000
{ MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 34.234.233.64:27017 closed
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:845:32)
    at _mongoose._promiseOrCallback.cb (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10)
    at Promise (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:5)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (/home/krishnadevz/excercise/node_modules/mongoose

Comment: You have 2 calls to the connect method, in the snippet you shared, try removing the first one, maybe that is the cause of the issue.