# Why my mongodb and node js connection is unsuccessful?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

**Hey Everyone. This is my Frist question on stack overflow .**

> I am tried to Connect my application with Mongodb. Even if I connect successfully to the server , the Mongodb connection is unsuccessful. I also set the Mongodb connection URL correctly.

**Here I changed the mongoose version and Ip addresses . But it didn't work.**

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app =express();
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8070;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URL,{
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useFindAndModify:false,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open",() =>{
    console.log("mongodb connection succes!");
})

app.listen(PORT,() =>{
    console.log(`server is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

[Here is given error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klYiF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076 try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error, it is mentioned that you have not whitelisted your IP address to Atlas cluster. You need to do that. You can see [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/ip-access-list/) how to add your current IP address on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist.

If this also don't work, then try changing your internet connection. Many times router block connection to 27017 port. So shifting to your mobile hotspot or other connection would work.

Comment: Ohh I set the ip address (put the current ip address and put the ip adress anywhere  ) but the error came. I'm sorry forgot to add it.

Comment: So now are you able to connect?

Comment: Which IP did you added ?

Comment: Current IP address... Also I added 0.0.0.0/0 this because it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share which ip address are you adding and where?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/slozuAo  ...... Soryy I don't know how to upload image in comment side....But I upload it to imgur.com

Comment: Everything seems correct. Are you getting same error?

Comment: Are you using any kind of proxy? Can you switch to another network and try?

Comment: I used my private network and later got  a VPN due to this problem....But it didn't fix it .

Comment: Your router might be blocking connection to 27017 port. Can you try using your mobile hotspot and test? I am sure using your mobile connection will solve this issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try it later. If it is ok , I will comment . Thanks for answering me .

Comment: Okay. Do let me know if changing to mobile connection worked or not.

Comment: Sir it is worked... I used another WiFi. Your last answer is correct (About connection error) ....Thanks Sir

Comment: Great to hear that this worked. Btw don't call me sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to whitelist your public IP address or else make the connection open to the world 0.0.0.0/0.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOtPQ.png)

Comment: Best practice is to whitelist your IP instead opening connection to the world.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem some days earlier. I don't know why it happened but I can give you a hack. You need to whitelist your IP address and also allow for anywhere both to your atlas cluster. This may fix the error as it fixed mine.

Comment: Allowing anywhere will cause trouble in security. Best practice is to whitelist only your server ip from whcih you want to access atlas.

Comment: Yeah definitely it will hamper security but for learning purposes, one can do it but surely not at the production level.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.... Given the same error.