# Can't connect the mongodb database and getting these error in my cpanel

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

```
returncode: 0
stdout:
> server@1.0.0 start
> node index.js

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/home/vaishna3/nodevenv/public_ftp/18/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:875:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/home/vaishna3/nodevenv/public_ftp/18/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:826:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-ngyyajr-shard-00-00.d0i0ct2.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-ngyyajr-shard-00-01.d0i0ct2.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-ngyyajr-shard-00-02.d0i0ct2.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-t70b7g-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
stderr:
```

pleasve solve the 503 service unavailable in my database

Comment: Did you follow the advise in the error message?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076`        hope it helps